# Laravel with Dynamodb

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, model, controller

I created a User model and UserController

and my **model** User.php is

```
<?php    
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

class User extends \Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = array('email');
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
}
```

when I create a object in **UserController**

```
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {    
        $user = new User();
```

it said the **$user = new User();(line30)** have **error**

> Argument 1 passed to Aws\AwsClient::__construct() must be of the type
>   array, none given, called in
>   C:....\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php
>   on line 30 and defined

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

You can't just go ahead and replace your User Eloquent model to extend DynamoDbClient and expect everything to work. DynamoDbClient is an entire client to handle your DB needs, not even close to being a Model that you can extend...

Just use a Laravel Package designed for this exact reason.

This is one that I just found: https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb

Comment: Good answer but the tone could be a bit less condescending..